# How would one solve this exponent problem without a calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

This is a problem on a non-calculator portion of an algebra 2 honors worksheet.

$$2^{24}=(3x-1)^8$$

Comment: Are you looking for both real and imaginary roots, or just real ones?

Comment: Real solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the eighth root.

$2^3 = 3x - 1$

$9 = 3x$

$x = 3$

Another solution is -7/3 because after the final square root, we take one of the negative solutions.

There are many other solutions, of course, according to the fundamental theorem of algebra. But, they end up with x being complex numbers.

Comment: $3$ is a solution, but the other solution is not $-3$.

Comment: you're right sorry

Comment: Can you explain how you got -7/3? Which square root are you talking about? Is it because of absolute value after the eighth root?

Comment: @NickSolonko: At one stage, you have $64 = 2^6 = (3x-1)^2$.  Taking the square root of both sides, we obtained $8 = 3x-1$.  But it is also possible that $-8 = 3x-1$; squaring both sides also produces $64 = (3x-1)^2$.  Then solving for $x$ yields $-7/3$.

Answer (score 1):

To find just real roots, start by taking the square root of both sides:

$$(3x-1)^4=2^{12} \text{ or } (3x-1)^4=-2^{12}$$

Since the right equation has no real solutions, we can ignore it. Next, take the square root of the left equation:

$$(3x-1)^2=2^6 \text{ or } (3x-1)^2=-2^6$$

Again, the equation on the right has no real solutions, so it can be ignored. Again take the square root of the left equation:

$$3x-1=2^3 \text{ or } 3x-1=-2^3$$

This time the equation on the right *does* have real solutions, so we can work with both to find the real roots.

$$
\begin{align*}
3x-1&=8\\
3x&=9\\
x&=3\\
\\
3x-1&=-8\\
3x&=-7\\
x&=-\frac{7}{3}
\end{align*}
$$